# Random high latency on net.Conn TCP writes

Tags: linux, go, tcp

I recently made some changes to some server software I run, and started to experience very some strange latency spikes in some writes down a net.Conn TCP connection. This is strange since the changes I made should have greatly decreased the overall network I/O of the server, although not of the particular connections that are blocking.

I'm looking for some help understanding what's happening under the hood of these writes, and any help in tools or other things to look at that might tell me what is going on here.

I've instrumented all the code around the connections, and narrowed it down to the net.Conn.Write function taking abnormally long on a seemingly arbitrary basis.

Some instrumented logs I have give an example. Here we see the `size` returned from the net.Conn.Write call, along with time and duration of the write in microseconds (the code is an application level code). The last write in this case takes 17 seconds, despite there being nothing special in either size or code.

```
{"size": 13, "time": "2023-11-24 02:28:36.444801912", "dur": 31, "code": 25}
{"size": 302, "time": "2023-11-24 02:28:36.444942292", "dur": 38, "code": 18}
{"size": 182, "time": "2023-11-24 02:28:36.445081266", "dur": 24, "code": 18}
{"size": 172, "time": "2023-11-24 02:28:36.445141647", "dur": 25, "code": 18}
{"size": 181, "time": "2023-11-24 02:28:36.445145097", "dur": 17936055, "code": 18}
```

I've been debugging this for several days and haven't managed to make any progress in identifying a root cause. What are some common reasons a TCP connection like this may hang for 17+ seconds, and what tools or other factors could I look at to help understand what's going on?

Clearly by these logs, there must be internal buffering of the TCP connection happening somewhere, as it's unlikely that any network round trip would complete in <25 microseconds. Could be some issue related to buffering and flushses?

Possibly related, some of the changes I made involve no longer listening on 0.0.0.0, instead listening on a specific IP address. Secondly, I have multiple IP addresses attached to the machine on the same network interface, and there maybe multiple parallel connectioning open to the same remote client on different local IPs.